# Script, scheduling tasks

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

[image]

This is the script that I started doing. I want to ask the user to make a change in the `crontab`.

How can I do this?

I have tried to find answer but I couldn't.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the `"`, and you should put spaces before/after the brackets `⌴[⌴ ... ⌴]⌴`. Here is what you could do :

```shell
#!/bin/bash

crontab -l

echo "Do you want to make a change (y/n) ?"
read YES_NO

if [ "$YES_NO" == "y" ]
then
    echo "Ok great, do it !"
    crontab -e
else
    echo "Too bad, go out !"
fi
```